Autodesk Platform Services (Forge) .NET SDK OssClient.DeleteObjectAsync() & OssClient.GetObjectDetailsAsync() NullReferenceException
I can successfully create a new object in the specified bucket using a local file as shown. This can be verified using the OSS Manager Tool
.
But, I'm unable to get the details for that object or to delete that object. The call is being thrown with a 'System.NullReferenceException' without any details. Access token & bucket key are the same as shown in the upload image, so those are not null.

All scopes were added to the token to ensure that wasn't the issue, even though it would have thrown a different error for that.

What is the proper way to successfully execute these methods?
I've tried using the name of the object, the objectId & the objectKey without success.

Are you using their latest Nuget package (1.1.0) ?
If yes, try downgrading to an earlier version.
I was running into the same issue earlier today, and this resolved it. I think they forgot to initialize their objectsApi field in the constructor of their OssClient in their latest relase of the SDK package.
Best

Thanks @Romain Bigare! I was using 'Autodesk.Oss' Version 1.1.0. When rolling back to Version 1.0.1, the calls are successful.

From the code base of our .NET SDK at ObjectsApi.gen.cs#L1227, it calls DELETE buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectKey to delete the objects/files directly. So, the objectKey should be the object name (filename), excluding the urn:adsk.objects:os.object:{{bucketName}}.
The string you passed is objectId, not objectKey.
For example, if your objectId is urn:adsk.objects:os.object:mybucket/test.ipt, then the objectKey is test.ipt.

Hello Eason, as mentioned in the OP, I unsuccessfully tried the ObjectId & ObjectKey. Rolling back the package version & then using the ObjectKey allowed the calls to work properly.
